# How can "How do you play guitar often?" be rephrased?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbs, word-order

How can "How do you play guitar often?" be rephrased, and which is the likeliest interpretation:

1. "In what way do you often play guitar?"
2. "How do you manage to play guitar (so) often?"
3. "How come you play guitar often?"
4. "How is it (possible) that you play guitar often?"
5. "How do you often play guitar?"

Comment: What are you trying to ask? "What technique do you mostly employ?" "How do you find the time to play your guitar?" "Why do you succeed in playing it?"

Comment: Any of these. Which of your 3 interpretations would cross your mind first?

Comment: I'm not sure if the example is meant to ask: *How OFTEN do you play the guitar?* The "how" question could be rephrased as *WHY do you play the guitar so often?*

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302670/how-can-how-do-you-play-tennis-often-be-rephrased/302680#302680). It isn't idiomatic English, so what would cross your mind is "What does he mean?"

Comment: By chance, are you trying to prove someone (a teacher/professor?) that your sample question is acceptable in British and American English? It's not but it might be in other English dialects.

Answer (score 1):

The following question is awkward sounding and as Kate Bunting commented, an English native speaker would wonder to him or herself "What does he mean?"

> 1. How do you play guitar often?"

The more conventional way is to say:

> 2. How OFTEN do you play **the** guitar?

With the  addition of the frequency adverb, often, the "how" question is ambiguous, confusing and the listener would probably ask the speaker to clarify.

Other plausible interpretations could be:

3. WHY do you play the guitar **so** often?
4. How do you MANAGE to play the guitar so often?
5. How CAN you play the guitar so often?

If somone considered "often" as a red herring, they might conclude that the speaker is asking:

6. How WELL do you play the guitar?

This matches more closely to the OP's first interpretation, *In what way do you often play guitar?*

7. How LONG do you play the guitar for?  (Ideally, it should be *How long have you been playing the guitar?*)
8. How MUCH time do you spend playing on your guitar?

Comment: Ack, I thought this was ELL.

Comment: Ungrammatical? If the sentence 'Do you play guitar often?' is acceptable, then surely 'How do you play guitar often?' is grammatical. Idiomatic, maybe not, but certainly grammatical.

Comment: The article and "so" is missing in "How do play (the) guitar (so) often?"  It doesn't sound right to me, and I suspect it wouldn't for many native speakers. @DW256 But I'll edit it

Comment: 'How do you play guitar often?' sounds irredeemable to me too. It _is_ probably ungrammatical without the 'so' (though 'In what manner/how do you often play [the] guitar?' work), but _unacceptable_ on outlandish-sounding grounds whether grammatical or not. _Incorrect_.